# Image doesn't show up when font called within Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.6, imagettftext

I'm new to Joomla dev and php so if I'm doing something stupid please let me know!

I'm creating a certificate to be printed after a user completes a quiz with their name, date, etc.  I've gotten the image to show up and text, but when I add the font nothing shows up.

Here's the base script I'm using and works (background image and font working):

```
$image_file = 'images/certificate_page.png';
$my_img = imagecreatefrompng ($image_file);
$font_size_big = 24;
$text_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 0, 0, 0 );
$font_file = 'FelipaRegular.ttf';  

imagefttext( $my_img, $font_size_big, 0, 5, 75, $text_colour, $font_file, "test with font"); 
imagestring( $my_img, 4, 30, 25, "test without font", $text_color );

header( "Content-type: image/png" );
imagepng( $my_img );

imagecolordeallocate( $text_color );
imagedestroy( $my_img );
```

When I tried to apply it within Joomla the problems started.  I'm calling it from within a template like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo JURI::root().'index.php?tmpl=certgenerator&quizmod='.$quizmod.'' ?>" />
```

and the file generator (certgenerator.php):

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
require_once("includes/variables_certificate.php");

$image_file = JURI::root().'templates/'.$this->template.'/images/certificate_page.png'; 
$my_img = imagecreatefrompng ($image_file);
$font_size_big = 24;
$text_color = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 0, 255, 0 );
$font_file = 'FelipaRegular.ttf';  

imagefttext( $my_img, $font_size_big, 0, 55, 75, $text_color, $font_file, "why u no work"); //if commented out image displays but not font obviously, as it's written now it returns a blank page
imagestring( $my_img, 4, 30, 25, "works", $text_color ); //works but doesn't include font

header( "Content-type: image/png" );
imagepng( $my_img );

imagecolordeallocate( $text_color );
imagedestroy( $my_img );
```

Reference:

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php
```

I've tried imagettftext vs imagefttext, no extension, with extension, bunch of stuff from the link above, all the same result. Any ideas?  I'm guessing (and hoping!) something stupid?

Comment: valid font file with the right permissions in the right directory?

Comment: Both scripts are in the same directory as is the font; though it could be a path issue within Joomla.  I've tried a bunch of different paths with no success - would Joomla require a certain path or location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PHP when working with files you should use JPATH_ instead if JURI. JURI is used for generating http URIs.

```
$image_file = JURI::root().'templates/'.$this->template.'/images/certificate_page.png';
```

Should be

```
$image_file = JPATH_SITE.'/templates/'.$this->template.'/images/certificate_page.png';
```

Not sure if this is the problem, and your code may well work as I have a sneaky suspicion that imagecreatefrompng() accepts http. But really it is the wrong way to go about it as it is a local file.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem - I beat you by a little bit but here's the check :)

Answer (score 0):

Paths are the bane of my existence!

```
$font_file = JPATH_SITE.'/templates/'.$this->template.'/images/font/FelipaRegular.ttf';
```